# Angular http get(or) post not working with nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular

When I am calling an Angular http get (or) post to my NodeJS application not working no error in console

```
 login(model) 
{
    debugger
        let options = new RequestOptions({
        headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' }) 
    });
    // var AppURL='https://staging.medicscloud.com/Dev/MedicsCloud/Mobile/MobileAuthentication/Login/?practiceID='+model.prccode;
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:4006/api/user/login', model)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            let user = response.json();
            if (user && user.token) {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            }
        }).subscribe();
        //.subscribe();
}
```

my nodejs code

```
router.get('/user/login/', function (req, res) {
console.log("hiiiiiiiiii            "+req.body,req.query)
// common.testapi().then(function (rows) {
//     if (rows) {
//         res.end("");
//     }
// }).fail(function (err) {
//     console.error("displayreport..." + err.body);
// });
res.end("hiiiiiii");
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Your `map` function is not  returning anything and I don't think subscribe works like that.

Try this:

```
login(model) 
    {
        debugger
            let options = new RequestOptions({
            headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' }) 
        });
        // var AppURL='https://staging.medicscloud.com/Dev/MedicsCloud/Mobile/MobileAuthentication/Login/?practiceID='+model.prccode;
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:4006/api/user/login', model)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                let user = response.json();
                if (user && user.token) {
                    // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                }
                return user; //<- return something
            }).subscribe((response)=> console.log(response));
            //.subscribe();
    }
```

Also, you would usually want your methods to return observables, then you would subscribe to them wherever you need them. The above code returns a subscription and if you are not experienced with async operations you will be wondering why some variables are `undefined`.

Comment: hi iam new to angular2. when i call http  method  its not going to hit url and no errors.please give me a solution.the above code also not worked for me

Comment: @ParsharamuluA do you see the request in your network tab? If you are using chrome, press F12 select the network tab from above and look for the relevant get request.

Answer (score 0):

This must be a CORS issue. Please ensure following headers set at server end when sending response to client. :

// Domain you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

// Request methods you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');

// Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in  requests
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);